# PHP Yii2 - Get attributes name of an Object

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I was wondering if there is a way to get just the attributes name? In the example I mean: *id, name, user*. I don´t need the values, just name of attributes.

```
app\models\Data Object
(
[_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => 
        [user] => 
    )

[_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => 
        [user] =>             
    )    
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `array_keys($model->attributes);`

Comment: @Bizley Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like the code in the comment but Yii also provides a function on `ActiveRecord` itself to get the attribute names:

```
$model->attributes();
```

Official docs:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#attributes()-detail

Comment: Excellente, both options do it! Thanks